# Polling one function after another, second function not firing correctly

Tags: jquery

---------ISSUE FIXED-----------

Not sure what the issue was as never got an error in the console, but the functions now work as expected.

I'm having an issue with two functions that poll delete and poll insert using Server Side Events

The delete poll works OK as can be seen from the console snippet below.

The problem is the insert poll, looking at the console, it shows:

Start of insert

End insert

Percentage complete 100

Inserting

It's not actually showing the number of records inserted and I'm struggling to get it to work correctly, any help would be appreciated.

Percentage complete 71
Percentage complete 74
Percentage complete 77
Percentage complete 80
Percentage complete 82
Percentage complete 85
Percentage complete 88
Percentage complete 91

Percentage complete 94
Percentage complete 97
Percentage complete 100
End Of Delete

status success

check status

Start of insert

End insert

Percentage complete 100

Inserting

```
$(function () {
    $("#submissionData").html("");
    $("#uploadMembers").on("click",function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        console.log("Form submitted");
        checkDeleteStatus();
    });

});
//Delete Polling
function checkDeleteStatus() {
    if (typeof EventSource === "undefined") {
        $("#status").append("<div>Sorry your browser does not support SSE</div>");
    }
    console.log("Start of delete");
    var source = new EventSource("/PollingDeleteOldProducts");

    source.addEventListener("message", function (event) {
        var data = JSON.parse(event.data);

        $.each(data.DisplayPollingInsert, function (key, value) {

            document.getElementById("uploadProgress").value = value.TotalPercentageDone;
            console.log("Percentage complete " + value.TotalPercentageDone);
            $(".progress-bar-custom").css("width", value.TotalPercentageDone + "%");
            $(".progress-bar-custom").html(value.TotalPercentageDone + "%");


            $("#ajaxRegister").html(`<p class=\"text-danger-custom\">${value.DisplayUpdate}</p>`);
            if (value.DisplayUpdate === "Completed Delete") {
                console.log("End Of Delete");
                source.close();
                console.log("status success");
                InsertProducts();
            }
        });

    },
        false);
}
//Polling
function checkStatus() {
    console.log("check status");
    if (typeof EventSource === "undefined") {
        $("#status").append("<div>Sorry your browser does not support SSE</div>");
    }
    console.log("Start of insert");
    var source = new EventSource("/PollingFileUpload");

    source.addEventListener("message", function (event) {
        var data = JSON.parse(event.data);

        $.each(data.DisplayPollingInsert, function (key, value) {
            document.getElementById("uploadProgress").value = value.TotalPercentageDone;
            console.log("Percentage complete " + value.TotalPercentageDone);
            $(".progress-bar-custom").css("width", value.TotalPercentageDone + "%");
            $(".progress-bar-custom").html(value.TotalPercentageDone + "%");


            $("#ajaxRegister").html(`<p class=\"text-success-custom\">${value.DisplayUpdate}</p>`);
            if (parseInt(value.TotalCount) > 0) {
                console.log("Inserting");
                if (parseInt(value.TotalCount) === parseInt(value.CurrentCount)) {
                    source.close();
                }
            }

        });
    },
        false);

    console.log("End insert");
}

function InsertProducts() {
    var formData = new FormData(document.getElementById("frmUploadProducts"));
    checkStatus();
    jQuery.ajax({
        enctype: "multipart/form-data",
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        async: false,
        type: "Post",
        url: "/InsertProducts",
        data: formData,
        cache: false,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (dataForm, status) {
            if (status === "success") {
                if (dataForm.Confirm === "NoTicket") {
                    $("#submissionData").append(`<p class=\"text-danger-custom\">${dataForm.Message}</p>`).show();

                } else if (dataForm.Confirm === "NoExcelFileUploaded") {
                    $("#submissionData").append(`<p class=\"text-danger-custom\">${dataForm.Message}</p>`).show();
                    $('#submissionData').html("");

                } else if (dataForm.Confirm === "OperationComplete") {
                    if (dataForm.Errors !== "") {
                        $("#submissionData").html("");
                        $("#submissionData").append(dataForm.Errors);
                        $("#uploadMembers").attr("disabled", true);
                    }
                }
                else if (dataForm.Confirm === "false") {
                    $("#ajaxRegister").html("");
                    $("#ajaxRegister").append(`<p class=\"text-danger-custom\">${dataForm.Message}</p>`).show();
                    $("#submissionData").html("");
                    $("#submissionData").append(dataForm.Errors);
                }
                else {
                    $("#submissionData").append(`<p class=\"text-danger-custom\">Something has went wrong</p>`).show();
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: In your `var source = new EventSource("/PollingFileUpload");` you don't have logging in your `source.addEventListener("message"` block (i.e first line of the handler function) so we don't know if it's getting any messages at all.  Also I'd recommend using `source.onerror` to log any errors.

Comment: Hi @user2740650 I don't think that is the issue if I run just function checkStatus(), then the polling works OK

Comment: Are you saying if you run **either** `checkDeleteStatus` or `checkStatus` they each work independently, but if you run both the second one doesn't work?

Comment: Hi @user2740650 yes, I had checkStatus working first, then added checkDeleteStatus when both worked I added them together, both work, but checkStatus does not now show the progress

Comment: In each of your handlers, you have `var data = JSON.parse(event.data);`.  Try logging that `data` object immediately after the `JSON.parse`.  I suspect maybe the data for both types of events are being delivered to the same handler, not both.  Then in each you use `$.each` to look for the data you expect, but maybe the other type of data is there and you're just not processing it.

Comment: Hi user2740650 not sure what the issue was as I tried again this morning and everything now working as expected